# Can I substitute an entire value with another value?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to replace one value with another. For instance, if the result of an expression is 0, I want to replace it with an empty string. I don't want to repeat the expression, or use an intermediate cell.

For example, instead of this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE))
```

I would like something like this, if there were a "CASE" function that did what I want:

```
=CASE(VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE),0,"")
```

Is there a function or syntax that does this? Basically just like `switch` but without the last "default" parameter. I want the default to be the value being checked, without having to repeat the expression.

I suppose I could do this:

```
=regexreplace(vlookup(A1,B:C,2,FALSE),"^0$","")
```

...but that's a bit ugly and probably very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern to replace zeros with blanks:

`=iferror( 1 / ( 1 / vlookup(A1, B:C, 2, false) ) )`

Comment: That replaces non-numerics with blanks as well, which is not what I want.

Comment: Please show what your data looks like. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.